# How can we track down which component is supposed to display the home page?

Tags: joomla, components, joomla1.5

I had a Joomla 1.0 site. I created a fresh new install of 1.5 and used the migrator to upgrade from 1.0. According to the installer all went fine.

But now when I access the homepage, it tells me `Component not found`. I remember I had a custom component setup `com_p` that displayed the home page.

How can I change in Joomla 1.5 which component will display the home page? How do I set the id of the component?

I used to have a code in joomla 1.0 index.php

```
if ( !$Itemid ) {
// when no Itemid give a default value
    $Itemid = 35;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Content Article Manager, you should be able to specify which article will be shown on the frontpage.

Comment: Yeah, a couple of them are ticked out. And they show up in the Front Page Manager, but the homepage is empty, 404 custom Joomla error and that are not the items I want for the home page, I need a custom module